# Посчитать сумму элементов матрицы

Tags: c++, матрицы

надо вычислить сумму элементов каждой строки матрицы v (4,5) или количество
положительных элементов столбцов этой матрицы по указанию пользователя.
Есть код, который создает матрицу указаного раземра и выводит ее (но почему-то только из положительных чисел). Но я не знаю, как считать элементы и как сделать это по выбору пользователя. Если вам не сложно, то буду очень благодарен за помощь.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
    int N, M;
    cout<<"Введите размер матрицы: ";
    cin >> N >> M;
    int ** A = new int * [N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        A [i] = new int [M];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            A [i][j] = ((rand() % 20));


 cout << "Ваша матрица:" << endl << endl;
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
 {
     for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
         cout << A[i][j] << " ";
     cout << endl;
 }

 cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            delete [] A[i];
        delete [] A;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Положительные числа, это числа которые больше «0», добавьте условие в эту строчку кода:

```
     If ( A[i][j] >0)
     {
          sum += 1;
     }
```

Таким образом в переменной sum вы получите количество положительных элементов